# Best way to add bleed to outline of image - Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production, creative-cloud, bleed

Wanting to add bleed to this image. I've so far made a cut line in illustrator and am wondering if there is a way like content aware in which I can create more image but only around the outline? I was thinking of using the silouhette enlarging it and then making a selection from that and filling in with content aware or even AI is its possible?

[image]

Comment: To be 100% honest.. if quality was the utmost concern.. I'd zoom in and go around the outside with a brush or the clone stamp tool, picking up colors from the artwork as I painted on an under-layer to manually add a bleed. This isn't the easiest or fastest way, but often yields the best results. I'm aware that today most want some quick one or two button solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Photoshop 2024's AI Generative fill for this (*see note below).  This is a new feature and is not available in older versions of Photoshop.

To avoid issues of copyright, which could prevent use of generative fill, I temporarily added a new layer, and painted in white to patch over the KFC logo, just so that I could create the example shown below.

Then, increase the canvas size as required, paint out the horrible black line on the left, and select the bottom portion of the image using the rectangle select tool, then  hit Generative Fill, and then Generate. Don't type in a text prompt for the fill, just leave it blank.

A new layer is created with the required fill. You can choose from one of three generative fill variations and choose the one you think will be suitable.

An example showing what can be achieved with the new Generative fill.

[image]

***Disclaimer**: I have no idea if this is legal to do with this particular image, since I don't know its origin. It could be copyright and if it is, you won't be able to use it legally. I am showing this edit solely for educational purposes.

Answer (score -1):

So, you must fill the extended area of this image:

[image]

Assumptions: For artistic reasons you are not going to stretch the image a little larger nor insert a wide enough white space to the left, right and bottom edges. And you also have some strict reasons why you cannot open the original collage and make a little less cropped copy.

Obviously the transparent areas in the left and right can become white, but you must somehow invest to the bottom edge (including the corners) more local cash.

Content aware fill will continue the edges of the cut banknotes surely quite well, but the banknote details will be obscured because Photoshop either cannot or doesn't want to generate fake banknotes. I guess it doesn't know New Zealand banknote details. An AI application maybe could know them, but I do not have access to such application.

The remaining possibility is to insert new layers which contain distorted (warp and   perspective) photos of banknotes. Of course, the photos of real used banknotes would be the best. Photoshop gives good tools for background removal and matching the size and colors. If you tile enough banknotes to a well scattered row you can cover the whole problem with a single photo.

I do not have such amount of New Zealand money, but I inserted three separate pieces of what I have. Actually they are game playing banknotes stolen from a webshop ad:

[image]

Not asked, but in your image KFC is somehow flattened and left in a shadow. Maybe a reason to check if KFC allows their marks to have a walk-on part. I tried to replace the mug with something more protruding and at least it looks round:

[image]

Unfortunately I do not have the pile of the banknotes. Trying to make your originals to fit makes them look distorted and unsharp. Making compositions needs high resolution photos. Screenshots become nearly always too unsharp.